# Does C# have a natural way to check regex match for single string and multiple regex, with single pass through string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, algorithm

Let's say I have a collection of regexes

```
IEnumerable<Regex> regexes = new[] { new Regex(@"\dpx"), new Regex(@"\dem"), new Regex(@"\dpt"), new Regex(@"\d%") };
```

and a very long string

```
string str = "n32kajnmnad ... "; // 1,000,000,000 chars long
```

Does C#/.NET have any natural way of checking whether contains any of the regexes, with a single pass through the string?

In other words, I want something approx. 4x as efficient as

```
regexes.Any(r => r.IsMatch(str)))
```

without rolling my own algorithm, if possible.

Comment: If you only want to pass it only once and don't need matches, why don't you just connect all regexes with or?

Comment: What stops you from using a simple regex like `\d(px|em|pt|%)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matching groups in Regex along with OR:

```
(abc)|(ghi)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/FBYQLu/1

You could also skip those groups but to make sure all the regexes from list are processed as if they were separate they are needed (suppose you have an OR in a single regex). And with those groups you could see which regex passed etc.